# What is the difference between "multi-language" and "multi-lingual"?

Tags: synonyms

As per my title, what is the difference between the terms "*multi-language*" and "*multi-lingual*", if any? Are they synonyms?

I found a reference that claims that "multi-language" refers to software, while "multi-lingual" is a broader term. Can someone confirm?

Comment: A *person* may be multilingual, and a *sign* may be multi-language, but it's not in some common dictionaries. Please post details of your "found a reference."

Comment: *[**Multi-language**](https://www.mbaskool.com/business-concepts/human-resources-hr-terms/15583-multi-language.html) is when something is **expressed in two or more languages**. Multi-language is also referred to as multi-lingual. A **person** who **has the ability** to speak/ write/ express himself in more than two languages  is said to be **multilingual.*** It's not very idiomatic to say *"He is multi-language"*.

Comment: Be aware that natural languages and programming languages are different beasts.

Comment: I am multi-lingual but I am most **definitely** not multi-language.

Comment: The primary difference is that language is a noun and lingual is an adjective.

Answer (score 2):

They are synonyms, but most of the time 'multilingual' is used to refer to a person or community that uses/knows multiple languages.

'Multi-language' is, though a synonym, more often used to refer to technology that supports multiple languages. Think about websites and software or a voice assistants like Google or Siri that understands and responds to commands from multiple languages.

But there is no 'definitive' answer since they can be used interchangeably.

Comment: I agree, Melanie. But ELU considers answers supported by recognised references or reasonable data to be most appropriate.

Comment: multi-lingual dictionary. As a translator/interpreter, I would most definitely not like the adjective multi-language used in connection with my skills. So I hardly think they are synonyms...